# Detect if user exits full screen video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, fullscreen

Is there a way to detect if a user exits full screen video.  I would like to reload my video if full screen mode is exited.  I have found some things on here about cancelFullScreen and exitFullScreen, but nothing I have found is working for me.  Any info will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "reload" do you mean start from the beginning? or force full screen again? either way these don't seem like desirable outcomes for the user?

Comment: My video is the opening to a website, I have a poster with overlay content.  If the video is played, full screen takes over and (obviously) the poster and overlay content disappear.  I would like to return to this original state (poster image and overlay content) if the user exits the full screen video

Comment: As best practices go, please ensure you provide a **skip >>** link as most intro videos for end users are frustrating... likewise be really careful not to try and force the user into re-watching something they've likely attempted to break out of.  Also note that you can only request full-screen... the user can deny the request and never go full screen (if so, what does the user see?)

Comment: The video is not on autoplay.  The poster and overlay content serve as an intro to the website, therefore the video is not forced on the user.  If the user decides to watch the video via a custom play button, then the video will be played fullscreen.  If they decide to exit then they will return to the sites initial state and can continue to navigate the homepage.  I simply need to detect when they exit the video, so that I can return things to the initial state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume this would depend on the player you are using for video. I would check the documentation which refers to that video player. A simple Google search got me these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+if+full+screen+video+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

```
    // Entering fullscreen mode
    $('video#my-video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
        var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
        var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

       // Now do something interesting
       //alert('Event: ' + event); 

    if (event == "FullscreenOn"){
    //do something when fullscreen on

    }


    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the alerts are working.  However, I am (at best) intermediate with javascript.  Can you explain what is contained in the 'event' variable.  How would I only fire an event when full screen is exited.  Sorry for my novice-ness

Comment: Thanks for that.  One more question...that works for firing an event when full screen is on, but if I change it to FullscreenOff and try to add a simple alert, it does not work.  Any idea why?

Comment: are you loading it on page load? Do you have a link I can see this on?

Comment: Now I'm running into another issue...I have gotten everything working properly and am reloading the video if the user exits full screen.  However, upon reload, my poster image does not reappear.  Any idea why that is happening.  Sorry to keep adding to this, but I can't find the answer anywhere

Comment: Create a jsfiddle  so I can better assist you. Without seeing your actual code I can't be of much more help.